# как отсортировать объекты по массивам

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

есть массив объктов:

```
[

 {category:1, product: 1},

 {category:1, product: 2},

 {category:1, product: 3},

 {category:2, product: 4},

 {category:2, product: 5},

 {category:3, product: 6},

 {category:4, product: 7}

]
```

нужно отсортировать массив по котегориям так чтобы на выходе был:

```
[
  [
    {category:1, product: 1},

    {category:1, product: 2},

    {category:1, product: 3}
  ],

  [
   {category:2, product: 4},

   {category:2, product: 5},
  ],
  [
   {category:3, product: 6},
  ],
  [
   {category:4, product: 7}
  ]
]
```

сортировать нужно по категориям и массивы должны быть динамическими.
никак не пойму как решить, попытался отсортировать по возростанию числа категорий, потом найти первый и последний индекс определённых категорий и при помощ `slice()` отрезать нужные объекты, но такой способ думаю не оптимальный

Comment: А числа в category идут подряд от 1 и дальше или там могут быть произвольные числа, с пропусками?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty  там могут быть произвольные числа

Answer (score 1):

А можно сразу вставлять элементы в нужные места.

```js
const arr = [
 {category:1, product: 1},
 {category:1, product: 2},
 {category:1, product: 3},
 {category:2, product: 4},
 {category:2, product: 5},
 {category:3, product: 6},
 {category:4, product: 7}
];

console.log(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const idx = acc.findIndex(e => e[0].category === cur.category);
  idx === -1 ? acc.push([cur]) : acc[idx].push(cur);
  return acc;
}, []));
```

Comment: Если массив небольшой, то, конечно, лучше так, не усложняя. Но если большой, лучше замерить затрачиваемое время на оба варианта, потому что с ростом структуры время на поиск нужного места может ощутимо увеличиваться.

Comment: Можно ещё использовать category как индексы и потом просто убрать дыры из массива. Но на перестройку массива тоже может уйти время)

Comment: полностью согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать временную промежуточную структуру, чтобы сгруппировать объекты по нужному ключу, а потом преобразовать её в нужный формат. Так мы расходуем больше памяти, но немного экономим на времени, потому что не нужно постоянно искать нужное место для текущего элемента, обыскивая строящуюся окончательную структуру.

```js
const data1 = [
  {category:1, product: 1},
  {category:1, product: 2},
  {category:1, product: 3},
  {category:2, product: 4},
  {category:2, product: 5},
  {category:3, product: 6},
  {category:4, product: 7},
];

const temp = data1.reduce(
  (acc, object) => {
    if (!acc[object.category]) acc[object.category] = [];
    acc[object.category].push(object);
    return acc;
  },
  {},
);

const data2 = Object.values(temp);

console.log(data2);
```

Можно ещё использовать ключ как индекс массива и потом вычистить дыры. Правда из-за чистки дыр мы по сути тоже используем временную структуру и на это тоже уйдёт память и время)

```js
const data1 = [
  {category:1, product: 1},
  {category:1, product: 2},
  {category:1, product: 3},
  {category:2, product: 4},
  {category:2, product: 5},
  {category:3, product: 6},
  {category:4, product: 7},
];

const data2 = data1.reduce(
  (acc, object) => {
    if (!acc[object.category]) acc[object.category] = [];
    acc[object.category].push(object);
    return acc;
  },
  [],
).filter(Boolean);

console.log(data2);
```